# Creating rounds for Rock Paper Scissor game with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner at javascript and am trying to make a five round game of rock paper scissors that keeps track of the wins and losses. I was able to create one game, however don't know how to make it so it repeats five times. Can anyone help me make it so it does rounds? I am guessing I need to do some type of for loop, but don't know what to place in the for loop. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks, 
Here's my code:

```js
/* Players Choice */
  let userInput = prompt('Rock, Paper, or Scissor?: ');
  console.log(userInput);

  if (userInput == 'rock'){
    console.log(userInput = 1);
  } else if (userInput == 'paper'){
    console.log(userInput = 2);
  } else if (userInput == 'scissor'){
    console.log(userInput = 3);
  }

/* Computers Choice */
  let compMove = Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 1;
  console.log(compMove);

  if (compMove == 1) {
    alert('Rock!');
  } else if (compMove == 2){
    alert('Paper!');
  } else if (compMove == 3){
    alert('Scissor!');
  }





/* Compare */
function result() {
  if (compMove == 2 && userInput == 1) {
    alert('You lose!');
  } else if (compMove == 3 && userInput == 1){
    alert('You Win!');
  } else if (compMove == 1 && userInput == 2){
    alert('You Win!');
  } else if (compMove == 1 && userInput == 3){
    alert('You Lose!')
  } else if (compMove == userInput){
    alert('Draw!');
  }
}

console.log(result());


function game() {
  for (let i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
  result() == 1;
  }
}

console.log(game());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to put your "`match`" within your `for-loop`.
- The `match`function returns the userInput and computerMove.

This code snippet plays 2 games as an example.

```js
var match = function() {
  /* Players Choice */
  let userInput = prompt('Rock, Paper, or Scissor?: ');
  console.log(userInput);

  if (userInput == 'rock') {
    console.log(userInput = 1);
  } else if (userInput == 'paper') {
    console.log(userInput = 2);
  } else if (userInput == 'scissor') {
    console.log(userInput == 3);
  }

  /* Computers Choice */
  let compMove = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  console.log(compMove);

  if (compMove == 1) {
    alert('Rock!');
  } else if (compMove == 2) {
    alert('Paper!');
  } else if (compMove == 3) {
    alert('Scissor!');
  }

  return {
    "compMove": compMove,
    "userInput": userInput
  };
}

/* Compare */
function result(compMove, userInput) {
  if (compMove == 2 && userInput == 1) {
    alert('You lose!');
  } else if (compMove == 3 && userInput == 1) {
    alert('You Win!');
  } else if (compMove == 1 && userInput == 2) {
    alert('You Win!');
  } else if (compMove == 1 && userInput == 3) {
    alert('You Lose!')
  } else if (compMove == userInput) {
    alert('Draw!');
  }
}

function game() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    var opt = match();
    result(opt.compMove, opt.userInput);
  }
}

game();
```

See? now the game start after every match.